# Ajax POST request not working - in dependency dropdown menue in laravel blade

Tags: ajax, laravel, drop-down-menu

Here I have a dropdown menu is like - countryName->CityName->ThanaName (ThanaName depends on CityName and CityName depends on countryName)

- First of all I fetch country name from database table.
- I passed country name through ajax as like as below.

```
  $(document).on('change', '[name=country]', function() {
           var country = $(this).val();
           get_city(country);
       });

       function get_city(country) {
           $.ajax({
               headers: {
                   'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
               },
               url: "{{route('get-city')}}",
               type: 'POST',
               data: {
                   country_name: country
               },
               success: function (response) {
                   var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                   if(obj != '') {
                       $('[name="city"]').html(obj);
                       AIZ.plugins.bootstrapSelect('refresh');
                   }
               }
           });
       }
```

And the route in web.php is like `Route::post('/get-city', 'CityController@get_city')->name('get-city');`

And in CityController , the get_city method is like

```
      public function get_city(Request $request) {
        $country_info = Country::where('status',1)->where('name', $request->country_name)->first();
        
        $cities = City::where('country_id', $country_info->id)->get();
        $html = '';
        
        foreach ($cities as $row) {
//            $val = $row->id . ' | ' . $row->name;
            $html .= '<option value="' . $row->name . '">' . $row->getTranslation('name') . '</option>';
        }
        
        
        echo json_encode($html);
    }
```

And this is working absolutely fine and it returns cityname according to its country name. But the problem is for thanaName that depends on cityName. For this my route is like `Route::post('/get-thana', 'ThanaController@get_thana')->name('get-thana');`

In ThanaController, the get_thana method is like

```
public function get_thana(Request $request) {
       
        $city_info = City::where('name', $request->city_name)->first();
        
        $thanas = Thana::where('city_id', $city_info->id)->get();
        
        $html = '';
        
        foreach ($thanas as $row) {
//            $val = $row->id . ' | ' . $row->name;
            $html .= '<option value="' . $row->name . '">' . $row->getTranslation('name') . '</option>';
        }
        
        
        echo json_encode($html);
    }
```

and the ajax code is like

```
$(document).on('change', '[name=city]', function() {
            var city = $(this).val();
            console.log(city);
            console.log('Here');
            get_thana(city);
        });

        function get_thana(city) {
            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                url: "{{route('get-thana')}}",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    city_name: city
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                    if(obj != '') {
                        $('[name="thana"]').html(obj);
                        AIZ.plugins.bootstrapSelect('refresh');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

But it show

> ***POST http://localhost/rul/ecom/get-thana 500 (Internal Server Error)***

Here is my ajax full code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        

        $(document).on('change', '[name=country]', function() {
            var country = $(this).val();
            console.log(country);
            console.log('country');
            get_city(country);
        });

        function get_city(country) {
            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                url: "{{route('get-city')}}",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    country_name: country
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                    if(obj != '') {
                        $('[name="city"]').html(obj);
                        AIZ.plugins.bootstrapSelect('refresh');
                    }
                }
            });
        }

//start another 
        $(document).on('change', '[name=city]', function() {
            var city = $(this).val();
            console.log(city);
            console.log('Here');
            get_thana(city);
        });

        function get_thana(city) {
            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                url: "{{route('get-thana')}}",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    city_name: city
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                    if(obj != '') {
                        $('[name="thana"]').html(obj);
                        AIZ.plugins.bootstrapSelect('refresh');
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        

    </script>
```

In browser network tab the error show like the below image when I change city.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ298.png)

Browser console tab: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3y7Jo.png)

Comment: in your get_thana method in controller you use `$city_info = City::where('name', $request->country_name)->first();` but you sent `city_name` from ajax request. and better use id instead of name to find data.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon thanks. Edited now. But same issue here!

Comment: still 500 error? and what's the error response you get in browser network tab?

Comment: Here is Browser network tab. https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmJna.pn                                                                             and here is Browser console tab: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GXPf.png

Comment: you are getting both 419 and 500? and network tab image is no longer available. provide network tab's response window.

Comment: Updated :   Network tab: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ298.png                                                                        console tab : https://i.stack.imgur.com/3y7Jo.png  now it is just error 500

Comment: Here is Network tab's response window : https://pastebin.com/mkGC5YpH

Comment: the error is pretty straight forward. Call to undefined method App\\Thana::getTranslation(). you dont have `getTranslation()` method in Thana Model.